# Problems with a couple of typing issues in Xcode when Archiving

Tags: xcode, type-conversion

When building I was not getting any warnings but when archiving I got a lot of typing warnings all involving stringWithFormat and one an issue using NSNotFound. I was able to resolve all the stringWithFormat problems except for one, and still remain stumped by the NSNotFound issue. These are listed below. Thanks for any help

The following code...

```
    if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.*s", [data length], [data bytes]] isEqualToString:@"Success"]) {
        return YES;
    }
```

Generates this warning for the format string...

> Field precision should have type 'int', but argument has type 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long')

The following code...

```
    if (![_response rangeOfString:@"|TreatmentCards|0|"].location == NSNotFound) {
         return NO;

    }
```

Generates...

> Comparison of constant 'NSNotFound' (9223372036854775807) with expression of type 'int' is always false

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when grabbing an index of a mutable array. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294347/warning-comparison-is-always-true-due-to-limited-range-of-data-type-causes-cras) is helpful for understanding the issue. The root of the issue is that the data type being returned will never hit `NSNotFound`. Instead, set it like:

```
NSUInteger location = [_response rangeOfString:@"|TreatmentCards|0|"].location;

if (location != NSNotFound) {
    return NO;
}
```

There might be a cleaner way but this should work. It also can be used for the problem above if you declare the length to a variable of data type `int`.